# Python multiprocessing.dummy and deepdish don't work together

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, hdf5, h5py

I have a problem with the `multiprocessing.dummy` package and `deepdish` to write compressed h5 files. 
This is what I am doing:

```
import deepdish as dd
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def writeThings(args):
    path, np_array = args
    dd.io.save(path, {'arr': np_array}, compression='blosc')

p = Pool(4)
p.map(writeThings, all_np_arrays_and_paths)
```

Everything works fine when I comment the deepdish save command out.
It seems that dd creates kind of corrupted files on Windows and Python detects this error, and just crashes. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you so much.

Comment: The error message would be helpful. Have you tried wrap the method call to save the data in an exception handler?

Comment: There is actually no error message. Python exists with an exception code 1073741819, and after searching for it I found one who had problems with writing h5 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, paths are distinct from each other, so I write to different files. However, still this *simple* function does not work. However, if I embed this into a `threading.Thread` class that has a lock and surround the `dd.io.save` command with `lock.acquire` and after writing the file `lock.release` everything works fine.

Here is a code snippet for everyone:

```
import threading

class writeThings(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, args, lock):
        super().__init__()
        self.args = args
        self.lock = lock

    def run(self):
        while self.args:
            path, np_array = self.args.pop()
            # Give this thread unique writing rights
            self.lock.acquire()
            dd.io.save(path, {"arr": np_array}, compression='blosc')
            self.lock.release()

lock = threading.Lock()
n_threads = 4
threads = []

for i in range(n_threads):
    threads.append(writeThings(args_junk[i],lock))

for i in range(n_threads):
    threads[i].start()

for i in range(n_threads):
    threads[i].join()
```